# Want to forward an ID or tag from HTML/PHP to JS (Keith Wood Countdown jQuery Plugin)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new around here. Nice to meet you.

I'm in a bit of a bind. For days I try to fix the infamous "final countdown" jQuery Plugin and get it to run wth MomentsJS. But I'm out of luck. The documentary is pretty much non-existent for non-professional web-coders (which I do not count to). So I tried other things... directly MomentsJS, but this results in a lot of reloading (AJAX), especially if there is a hiccup, and I can't use more than one timer on a page. Then I got back to Keith Wood's Countdown/Timer plugin, and I finally got it to run. Also thanks to StackOverFlow articles. But, I want to optimize the code - and this is where my problems set in.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO:**

- I want to create a simple Countdown/Timer for a webpage (layout is
  currently not my concern
- It has to be server-time/timezone aware and not focus on the
  client/browser time

**WHAT MODULES AM I USING:**
 - jQuery
 - Keith Wood's Countdown jQuery Plugin v2.0.2
 - currently HTML

**WHAT AM I TRYING TO ACHIEVE:**
 - I want to have one HTML file that then links to .js files to clean up
   the main HTML file from scripts (nobody should see that, and I use
   more scripts/functions on the page where this will be integrated
   anyway)
 - I want to forward an ID/class/array however

**Here is the code so far:**

**HTML**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Countdown</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.countdown.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script src="timer.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

COUNTDOWN 1

<div id="defaultCountdown" data-end="Sep 22, 2016 00:00:00 +0000"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function($){

    // TIMER

            function serverTime() {
                var time = null;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'servertime.php',
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function (text) {
                        time = new Date(text);
                    },
                    error: function (http, message, exc) {
                        time = new Date();
                    }
                });
                return time;
            }

            $(function () {
                $("#defaultCountdown").countdown({
                    until: new Date('Sep 22, 2016 00:00:00 +0000'),
                    serverSync: serverTime
                });
            });


})(jQuery);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>
```

Now here is the thing: you see the "data-end" tag I set in the div, this value in there should be forwarded to the JS, more specifically the line

```
until: new Date('Sep 22, 2016 00:00:00 +0000'),
```

So instead of the lengthy date, there should be a variable that reads out the numeric value from the HTML file (see "data-end") so that I don't have to mess with the JS file every time I update the timer. Which is also really time consuming if I want to trigger more than one countdown/timer. But sadly, I don't know how. I tried the .attr() code, but it didn't work. Either the JS drops an Error per day/hour/minute (NaN), or nothing shows up at all.

I'd also like to change a couple of things if possible, namely:

- The time format (to something like YYYY/MM/DD Hrs/Min/Sec
- the time zone (currently, the server where this is sitting on is
  GMT+1, but I want to have control over that)

I'm a freshmen in terms of code, I can walk around some basic stuff, but if it comes to actually forwarding values and working with them, I'm lost in the ocean.

Any help in a timely manner would be greatly appreciated - maybe it's something really simple I didn't think of yet. So thanks in advance

Comment: generally to access that `dataset` attribute it would be something like `document.getElementById('defaultCountdown').dataset.end` so you could change your code to `until: new Date( document.getElementById('defaultCountdown').dataset.end )`

Comment: Thank you very, very much, this worked for me and solved hours of frustration for me. Guess JS is not my forte after all

Answer (score 0):

Welcome aboard.

To get the value from the div you can use in the js

```
$(function () {
     $("#defaultCountdown").countdown({
         until: $('#defaultCountdown').data('end),
         serverSync: serverTime
     });
 });
```

2. for the timezone you can use `date_default_timezone_set()`. More Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
3. The coundoun.js expects the time format in a certain way. The NaN you get I suspect is from your attempt to change it

Comment: I guess I won't be messing with the time format then. Your code idea sadly didn't work however. What did work for me was `until: new Date( document.getElementById('defaultCountdown').dataset.end )`

Comment: There was a typo, missing a #. Try it now, to have jQuery allover

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jQuery so not sure whether or not the following would actually work but perhaps you could try:

```
$( function() {
    this.countdown({
        until: this.dataset.end,
        serverSync: serverTime
    } );
}.bind( $("#defaultCountdown") ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this didn't work - see answers above